# AdMob error Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, admob, linker-errors

I've scanned the internet for all possible solutions to my problem, but I have not been able to find an answer. I've tried cleaning and reopening xcode. It works fine on the simulator, but I get the following error when I run it on the device :-

```
Ld /Users/krishwadhwana/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tricenter-comzufishylbsifovkzysenwtyyh/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Straight\ Lines/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Tricenter.build/Release-iphoneos/Tricenter.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Tricenter normal arm64
        cd "/Users/krishwadhwana/Documents/Coding/My Development Main/Straight Lines"
        export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
        export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.1.sdk -L/Users/krishwadhwana/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tricenter-comzufishylbsifovkzysenwtyyh/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Straight\ Lines/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/krishwadhwana/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tricenter-comzufishylbsifovkzysenwtyyh/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Straight\ Lines/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/krishwadhwana/Documents/Coding/My\ Development\ Main/Straight\ Lines/SDKs/GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS-7.6.0 -filelist /Users/krishwadhwana/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tricenter-comzufishylbsifovkzysenwtyyh/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Straight\ Lines/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Tricenter.build/Release-iphoneos/Tricenter.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Tricenter.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -dead_strip -fembed-bitcode -Xlinker -bitcode_verify -Xlinker -bitcode_hide_symbols -Xlinker -bitcode_symbol_map -Xlinker /Users/krishwadhwana/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tricenter-comzufishylbsifovkzysenwtyyh/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Straight\ Lines/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/krishwadhwana/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tricenter-comzufishylbsifovkzysenwtyyh/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Straight\ Lines/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Tricenter.build/Release-iphoneos/Tricenter.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Tricenter.swiftmodule -framework SystemConfiguration -framework StoreKit -framework MessageUI -framework EventKit -framework EventKitUI -framework CoreTelephony -framework CoreGraphics -framework GoogleMobileAds -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework AdSupport -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/krishwadhwana/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tricenter-comzufishylbsifovkzysenwtyyh/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Straight\ Lines/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Tricenter.build/Release-iphoneos/Tricenter.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Tricenter_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/krishwadhwana/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tricenter-comzufishylbsifovkzysenwtyyh/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Straight\ Lines/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Tricenter.build/Release-iphoneos/Tricenter.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Tricenter

    ld: '/Users/krishwadhwana/Documents/Coding/My Development Main/Straight Lines/SDKs/GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS-7.6.0/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADBannerView.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error tells you you must either enable or disable bitCode.

Go to targets-build settings and use the search bar to search for bitCode. 
Most likely it is turned on so you should turn it off. Than clean project and you should be good to go.

Comment: Nope. Did not change anything

Comment: Bitcode works with the adMob SDK since you asked this question. Download the latest version and turn bit code back on. Otherwise try cleaning your derrived folder in Xcode and clean your Project.